# My DLLs are strong named, but WSPBuilder reports they are not

Tags: gac, strong-typing, wspbuilder

WSPBuilder

Version: 0.9.8.0830
Created by Carsten Keutmann
GPL License 2007

Install and deploying [MYDLL]
Unable to deploy solution
Inner exception(1): This solution contains one or more assemblies targeted for the global assembly cache. You should use a strong name for any assembly that will be in the global assembly cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, but not the solution, it seems the project I have which is really a 12 hive, is also set to output a class library, this class library is getting included in the WSP.

So... I need to ensure the bin folder is really excluded from the build process. 
I set the value in program files but no reaction yet...

Now going to restart the server...

**Later:** Ok - the fix is to restart the server, for some reason this helped

Comment: Somehow, none of the mentioned things work for me... including the restart of the server...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues but what worked for me was to delete all the files in the bin and obj folder and then rebuild the WSP.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting some strange errors (can't remember the exact message) when using `Delay sign only` option for one project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue, one solution, multiple projects, the one failing to compile is using an object from another project.

I've tried clearing the bin & obj folder, as well as restarting the server. I think I'll copy the files dll to the gac using gacutil instead.